# Access a php function in a different file

Tags: php, oop

I am getting an error that a file in a required_once statement can not be found. Full disclosure; I'm not a complete n00b but I'm not far off when I comes to php.

#### Helpers file

In a file, dedicated to a class inside a Models folder, I am trying to require a file which is inside a sibling folder. I have tried to declare namespaces, tried to require and then 'use' the file, I try one or the other, try all three or any combination, all fail only with differing but similar error messages.

This always provides the first error:

```php
// Models/Weather.class.php
<?php

require_once '../assets/helpers.php';
```

> Warning: include(..\assets\helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Models\Weather.class.php on line 5

The helpers file starts something like this:

```php
// assets/helpers.php
<?php

/** 
* Send a GET request using cURL
*/ 
function curl_get($url, ...
```

VS Code hints to where the file can be found while I am typing the php, so I'm fairly sure I'm referencing the correct file in the correct location, but when I run the script in the xampp I get the error.

When I use an absolute path to the file there is no problem, but why would I need to? I would like to be able to use the function in the helpers.php file in my class methods using the relative file path.

#### Class file reference

Now when I use the absolute path, I get the next error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DB' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 7

```php
// index.php
<?php

require_once 'Models/Weather.class.php';
require_once 'Models/DB.class.php';

$DB = new DB('weather'); // line 7
```

#### Using 'use'

If I do the same but add the line `use Models\DB;` The error message changes to

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Models\PDO' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 10

Line 10 refers to the same line as above, the line creating a DB class instance.

I've been looking at this code for a number of days now trying different angles. This should be easy, include one file in an other file. Just use `include` or `require` and Bob's your uncle, easy peasy right. That's what I thought, but I'm pulling my hair out and I'm getting no further. I'm sure it's something insignificant, I'm overlooking something...can you help me out?

---

#### UDPATE

So still errors but thanks to @Genhis I implemented the `spl_autoload_register()` autoloader from a comment in the docs, with an echo to see what is being autoloaded, and I created a test file with ony one require and an instantiation;

```php
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
  if (file_exists($class_name . '.php')) { 
    require $class_name . '.php'; 
    echo $class_name . ' exists'. "\n<br>";
    return TRUE;
  } 
  echo $class_name . ' does not exists' . "\n<br>";
  return FALSE;
});

use db\DB; // gave the classes their own dir
$db = new DB('weather');
```

Now the first output is:

> Models\DB exists
>   Models\PDO does not exists
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'db\PDO' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 15

The DP class has an options private variable:

```php
private $options = [
   PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
];
```

When I remove the variable the error comes when I try to establish a connection to the database. Do I need to include/require pdo (there goes more hair)?

Comment: Have you considered using autoloading (Composer)? Time (and hair) saver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the answer, and it was in large part due to my inexperience with php.

I should not have been `require`-ing the files where the classes were being defined but in the files they were being called/instantiated.

So this:

```php
// index.php
<?php

require_once 'Models/Weather.class.php';
require_once 'Models/DB.class.php';

$DB = new DB('weather');
```

..is where I should have included the `helpers.php` file. Because even though I was using a function from the `helpers.php` file in the class definition, that function was only used from where I was instantiating that class. In this case the `index.php` file.

So adding an include/require here...:

```php
// index.php
<?php

require_once 'Models/Weather.class.php';
require_once 'Models/DB.class.php';
require 'assets/helpers.php';

$DB = new DB('weather')
```

...solved all the problems.

Why require-ing the file in the wrong location caused the DPO error messages I still don't understand.

I'll leave the question because for me it was kind of an "Aha, I get it now" moment. 
Thanks for the input, person who has by now deleted their comment, using an autoloader is quite useful and I will include an autoloader in the files I use the classes!

Answer (score 0):

> When I use an absolute path to the file there is no problem, but why would I need to?

If the file is included in other files, then your relative path is from the first one - `{main}` file.

Consider this - if you call `dir1/include1.php` directly, everything works; if you call `index.php` first, you get an error:

**root/index.php**

```
include("dir1/include1.php");
//error: can't find file "root/../dir2/include2.php"
```

**root/dir1/include1.php**

```
include("../dir2/include2.php");
```

**root/dir2/include2.php**

To cope with this problem, I used absolute paths when I had to include helper functions and similar files.

---

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DB' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 7

You should use either `use` statement or fully qualified names if your classes have namespaces.

---

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Models\PDO' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 10

Your class `DB` depends on another class which hasn't been loaded. You should use a function to deal with loading classes on demand (e.g. [`spl_autoload_register()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)) or use a framework, such as [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).